# Is there a way in MFC (OLEDB) to refresh inserted rows in SQLServer?

Tags: c++, sql-server, mfc

first time asking here.

I've been tasked with migrating some 20+ years old MFC code using OLEDB connection (atldbcli.h) from Access to SQLServer and i've encountered the following problem: 
before the migration, after inserting a new row into the database we used to call  `HRESULT GetData(_In_ int nAccessor)` on our `CAccessor` derived table classes to retrieve the newly inserted row complete with its *IDRow*.

After the transition to SQLServer this function seems to do nothing at all, it doesn't even launch any error.

Is there any way to solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Show us how what flags you provided to the command.

Comment: I use the following property flags: `PropSet.AddProperty(DBPROP_IRowsetChange, true);``
    PropSet.AddProperty(DBPROP_UPDATABILITY, DBPROPVAL_UP_INSERT |
                        DBPROPVAL_UP_CHANGE | DBPROPVAL_UP_DELETE);`.